# "Stickied thread" or "sticked thread", when talking about internet forum thread

Tags: orthography

What is the more correct form? Quick Google research tells that first form is more popular, but don't give a definitive answer about what is the most appropriate.

Comment: If you would like a "definitive answer," I would suggest supplying more context, so that it's abundantly [clear](http://www.cookinfrance.com/images/caramel-hazelnuts-2.jpg) what you are [referring to](http://www.northwoodsfalconry.com/wp-content/uploads/DSC_0026-640x548.jpg).

Comment: Oh, ***stuck*** _threads!_ Why didn't you just say so? ;^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Threads are *sticky*, metaphorically, and in the realm of web publishing, *sticky* has come to be used as a verb, meaning to *make a post “sticky”*.

On websites and other systems where materials are displayed in chronological lists— blogs and journals, discussion forums, news feeds— new items are usually displayed at the top of the screen, so the first item you see is always the newest. Older items get pushed down until they fall off the bottom. To keep an item at the top, the editor or moderator employs a tool applying whichever metaphor the creators of the underlying software preferred:

- We *[sticky](http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts)* a post in software like WordPress or Drupal, or services like Tumblr or Reddit. It is *sticky* because it adheres to the top of the screen.
- On a Facebook Page, and in some other systems, we *[pin](https://www.facebook.com/help/239180129497043)* a post. It is *pinned* just as one would pin something onto a bulletin board to highlight it or to [pin it down](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/pin-down) to prevent it from moving.

The Ultimate Bulletin Board (UBB), an influential early forum software package first published in 1996, gave moderators the ability to "[feature topic](http://www.ubbcentral.com/support/docs/ubbclassic/UBB6all.html)," as did the EZboard service around the same time. It reflects a shift away from the free-form, unregulated discussion of old-fashioned Bulletin Board Systems (BBS's) and Usenet, and software like WWWBoard or WIT that mimicked them. As the Internet was commercialized, service owners wanted to manage and direct conversations and sought tools that offered greater control. But that's all off-topic for this site.

It's hard to nail down when the terminology to *make sticky* was first adopted or when we began to see *sticky* used as a verb in and of itself. These days, at least in this narrow realm, the verb form has become familiar to the point where references to a *stickyed thread* or *stickied thread* are not uncommon.

Comment: That's clarifies somewhat.